# Accidentally terminating installing restricted extras and vlc during installation

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, vlc

I tried to install restricted extras and vlc by entering the following code:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras && sudo apt install vlc
```

I then accidentally terminated the process and now, whenever I try to install anything (anything at all), I get the following recurring message:

```
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 16338 (apt)
```

I tried to stop the process by typing:

```
kill -9 16338
```

but was unsuccessful. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can kill the process and restore the ability to install what I want?

Comment: wait for a while or just reboot your system and it should be resolved ... The package name, however, is `ubuntu-restricted-extras` not `restricted extras`

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly Raffa. Yes, the actual coding i used was: sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras: I reproduced a shortened version above simply for brevity. Apologies if I've confused the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lock at `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` was invoked by `apt` the front end for `dpkg` ... The reason is to prevent two instances or more of `dpkg` running at the same time as this would caus problems.

Removing the lock at `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` in some cases will allow such a problem to happen if the back-end i.e. `dpkg` is still running which it might be. It is only done as a last resort if the problem persists after rebooting your system.

If a user waits for some time the lock will be removed automatically when it is safe to run `dpkg` or `apt` once again without causing problems.

`process 16338 (apt)` is already dead. You killed it when you terminated the process assuming you pressed ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> ) or just closed the terminal window.

So I would advise you to wait a bit longer then try again. However, if this persists for a very long time, probably rebooting your system is the safest workaround in this situation since it will terminate any instance of `dpkg` that is still running and the lock will be removed naturally.

You might, however, end up with broken installation of the two packages you interrupted. If that happens, you need to run the following commands in the order below:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> sudo dpkg --configure -a
> or Try This one
> sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a ` will not work for the same reason (the lock) and removing `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` (although it might work in this case since it's obvious what package invoked the lock) is not always a good idea ... so I would wait.

Comment: Did you try to reboot and then try again ??

Comment: And thanks for informing on matter

Comment: `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` is invoked by `apt` the front end for `dpkg` ... the reason is to prevent two instances or more of `dpkg` running at the same time as this would caus problems ... removing the lock `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` in some cases will allow such a problem to happen ... If a user waits for some time the lock will be removed so it is safe to run `dpkg` or `apt` once again without causing problems.

Comment: I rebooted and can now install other packages. I'm not knowledgeable enough with linux to understand everything you mentioned but I'm doing my own general research and learning more as I go. Your answers definitely contribute to my knowledge so thank you very much for taking the time to consider my problem in depth, it is very much appreciated.