# cache problem in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

how can i solve this problem in ubuntu 22.04

```
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3649 (apt) 
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3649 (apt) 
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3649 (apt) 
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3649 (apt)
```

Comment: Two or more things are trying to run updates simo. Stop all but one of them.

Comment: how can i stop them

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404090

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what you are trying to achieve (install software)?

You should probably wait for the `apt` process to finish updating.
You could also reboot your machine.
If you have applications running, like Software Center, Software Updater, Synaptic package manager, close them.

Comment: yes i was trying to install a software cisco packet tracer in my ubuntu mashine