# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade hanging

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, freeze, lock

I need some help figuring out what happened and how to fixed my Ubuntu distribution upgrade.
I decided to upgrade to 22.04LTS from 20.04LTS last night and ran into a problem where its hanging. Below is the process it hanged on since last night and nothing changed hours after waiting. [process upgrade is hanged on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywD5t.jpg)

Then i tried the following to fix the upgrade package
`sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt dist-upgrade -f`

And now im in a cache lock that wont get unlocked. Trying to cancel the command does nothing and now I cannot use the terminal. I dont want to restart the computer because I'm afraid itll mess something up. Please help.
[waiting for cache lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjDER.jpg)

Comment: Information here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1404071 and help(*if you need it*) here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1238355